# Is it possible to add a filename in a link label and have behind the path of the path?

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio

I want to load a `file path` in a `link label control`  `windows forms` and display only the the name in the `link label` but when the `label` is clicked to open the file from the path.

**I did this but I have to display in the `link label` the entire file path, witch I don't want to.**

```
private void linkPdfLabel__LinkClicked(object sender, LinkLabelLinkClickedEventArgs e)
{
    Process process = new Process();
    process.StartInfo.FileName = linkPdfLabel_.Text;
    process.Start();
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can consider using one of the 2 solutions. One of which is to use `Tag` property to assign an absolute file path and use it when clicked.

*example code:*

```
void CreateLink(string absoluteFilePath)
{
    _linkPdfLabel_.Tag = absoluteFilePath;
    _linkPdfLabel_.Text = Path.GetFileName(absoluteFilePath);
}

void linkPdfLabel__LinkClicked(object sender, LinkLabelLinkClickedEventArgs e)
{
    Process process = new Process();
    process.StartInfo.FileName = (string)linkPdfLabel_.Tag;
    process.Start();
}
```

---

Another way is to use a property called `Links` which is a `LinkCollection` which holds a collection of `Link` objects. You can use this to get the full link instead of the text.

*example code:*

```
void CreateFileLink(string absoluteFilePath)
{
    linkPdfLabel_.Text = Path.GetFileName(absoluteFilePath);

    var link = new LinkLabel.Link();
    link.LinkData = absoluteFilePath;
    linkPdfLabel_.Links.Add(link);
}

void linkPdfLabel__LinkClicked(object sender, LinkLabelLinkClickedEventArgs e)
{
    Process process = new Process();
    process.StartInfo.FileName = (string)linkPdfLabel_.Link[0].LinkData;
    process.Start();
}
```

Comment: I used the first solution. Worked like a charm. Thank you for your time!